# Is it possible to create packages with the same name in different organizations?

Tags: ckan

Is it possible to create packages with the same name in different organizations?

As far as I tested, it cannot be done. E.g. the following script tries to create the same package "testpackage" in two different organizations (org1 and org2), the first creation in org1 is ok but the second reports an "That URL is already in use" error.

```
#!/bin/bash

API_HOST=$1
API_KEY=$2

echo "--> Create org1"
(curl -s -S -X POST http://${API_HOST}/api/3/action/organization_create -H "Authorization: ${API_KEY}" -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{ 
   "name": "org1"
} 
EOF

echo "--> Create org2"
(curl -s -S -X POST http://${API_HOST}/api/3/action/organization_create -H "Authorization: ${API_KEY}" -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{ 
   "name": "org2" 
} 
EOF

echo "--> Create package testpackage in org1 (success)"
(curl -s -S -X POST http://${API_HOST}/api/3/action/package_create -H "Authorization: ${API_KEY}" -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{ 
   "name": "testpackage",
   "owner_org": "org1" 
} 
EOF

echo "--> Create package testpackage in org2 (failure)"
(curl -s -S -X POST http://${API_HOST}/api/3/action/package_create -H "Authorization: ${API_KEY}" -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{ 
   "name": "testpackage",
   "owner_org": "org2" 
} 
EOF
```

I tend to think organization as "isolated" namespaces, thus I wonder if I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Dataset URLs are `/dataset/dataset_name` (they don't include the organization's name in the URL), so two datasets with the same name would have the same URL.

This is because organizations were only added into CKAN fairly late.